# 403 Forbidden for suspend controller methods with basic authentication after migration to Spring Boot 3

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-mvc, spring-security, kotlin-coroutines

I recently migrated my Spring Boot MVC Kotlin project to Spring Boot 3. A basic auth is used for a REST controller (configured via `SecurityFilterChain` - also migrated from `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` based security). Since then, all calls to endpoints that are handled by **suspend** controller methods return 403. For the other endpoints it works fine.

All endpoints worked fine before the migration. When we make a controller method not suspend (using `runBlocking`), it works fine.

Interesting is, that the body of the controller method is executed. I noticed, that the request is passed through the security filter chain more than once, and it is in the default `AnonymousAuthenticationFilter` where it gets marked as unauthorized. The request param there does not contain the required auth headers, even if it does during the first pass through.

Some of the default `HttpSecurity` logic is disabled:

```
http
    .csrf().disable()
    .headers().disable()
    .sessionManagement().disable()
    .securityContext().disable()
    .requestCache().disable()
    .servletApi().disable()
    .apply(DefaultLoginPageConfigurer()).disable()
    .logout().disable()
```

It seems that when coroutines are involved, the authorization logic is triggered twice. Once it works correctly. For the second time it fails because of missing auth headers.

I tried enabling the disabled defaults, but that did not help.

Comment: Why not just look in your debug logs?

Comment: I did, but was not much wiser from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some more debugging and consultation with some Spring experts, I found out what was it about. It was a combination of three factors:

1. In the new Spring version, not only the initial request processing (dispatcher type "REQUEST") goes through the security chain, but in case of async calls like those I have with Kotlin suspend handler methods, even the asynchronous processing started in a new thread have to go through it (dispatcher type "ASYNC"). That means the authorization is done twice.
   2.`BasicAuthenticationFilter` is a `OncePerRequestFilter` that runs only in the first filtering round - security context is not updated this time.
2. As we have storing of security context in between requests disabled `http.securityContext().disable()`, it is missing in the second filtering round and so the request comes out as unauthorized.

There are several possible solutions to this. Either disabling of the security chain processing for requests with the "ASYNC" dispatcher type, enabling to remember security context in between requests, or some other.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Your error occurs when you are trying to add an asynchronous request to an application that handles security operations by thread (not by coroutine).

To use **suspend fun** in a controller, you must use your custom *CoroutineSecurityContext* (like [this](https://blog.jdriven.com/2021/07/propagating-the-spring-securitycontext-to-your-kotlin-coroutines/) one).

### Some notes

It is important to understand that using asynchronous and synchronous methods in an application is bad practice as it can lead to blocking of threads and slow performance since synchronous requests can block threads.

I had the same issue with uploading to AWS S3 and using the SDK for Kotlin. I solved it with runBlocking/launch, that's enough for me. In the future, I may switch to the reactive stack depending on performance requirements.

Comment: This would not help in this case. We wanted to use the default Spring security filter and it does not work with our custom context. The same problem would arise if we used the Spring `@Async` instead, so it isn't bound to coroutines - Spring MVC should be able to handle them.